# Lazy property initialized every time it is accessed

Tags: ios, swift

In the code below I have a Service class that owns an array of SubService objects. Subservices take a serviceDelegate parameter in the initialization in order to be able to send results back to the Service which then is able to determine if it is ready only when all the subservices are ready.

I'm using a lazy property because its initialization uses self and swift doesn't allow to use self before **self** is fully initialized.
Lazy properties are supposed to be initialized only the first time they are accessed and then are treated as normal stored variables.

The problem I'm having is that, after the initialization, when the Service receives the onSubServiceReady() callback and accesses subservices.....the initialization is done again, a new SubService object is instantiated. 
So maybe there's something I am missing on how lazy works.

```
class SubService{
  init(serviceDelegate: ServiceDelegate){
  ...
  // SIGNAL THAT SUBSERVICE IS READY TO THE SERVICE
            t4fServiceDelegate?.onSubServiceReady(true)
  }
}

protocol SubServiceDelegate{
  func onSubServiceReady(_ isSubServiceReady: Bool)
}

class Service: SubServiceDelegate{
  lazy let subservices: [SubService] = [SubService(serviceDelegate: self as ServiceDelegate ) ]
  init(){
  ...
  _ = self.t4fSubServices // need to initialize the lazy property so that each subservice starts its function
  }

  // From SubServiceDelegate
  public func onSubServiceReady(_ isSubServiceReady: Bool) {
    var allSubServicesConnected = false
    for subservice in subServices {
      if subservice.isConnectionReady { allSubServicesConnected = true }
    }
    isServiceReady = allSubServicesConnected
  }

}
```

Comment: I have modified the question reusing the same example. Now it's about lazy properties not working as they are supposed to do

Comment: I think I have found the problem: when the subservice calls the callback onSubServiceReady, we are still in the Service init function so basically Service is not fully initiated yet swift thinks that  the lazy property is being accessed for the first time